# Intuition on Changing Order of Summations

Tags: summation

> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left[\sum_{j=i}^{\infty}f(i,j)\right]=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{j}f(i,j)\right]
> $$

I have trouble understanding the change of order of this summation. I know that
$$
1≤i≤j≤\infty
$$
however, I can't seem to make sense of this even with manually comparing each sum of both double summations.

---

In the left side, we always have the sums: $$
S_1=f(1,1)+\dots f(1,\infty)
$$
$$
S_2=f(2,2)+\dots f(2,\infty)
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
so the total sum

$$
S=\sum S_n
$$
looks like summing each element of an $N\text{x}N$ matrix as $N\to\infty$

---

In the right side, we have the sums:

$$
S_1=f(1,1)
$$
$$
S_2=f(1,2) + f(2,2)
$$
$$
S_3=f(1,3)+f(2,3) + f(3,3)
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
The total sum $S$ looks like summing the top-right to bottom-left entries of a "pyramid" structure, which looks like the earlier matrix but deformed and slanted. However, I do not want to just assume that this is the case since I am working with infinite sums.

Is there a better intuition on how changing order of summations work so that I may extend it to more difficult scenarios particularly in the proof of the convolution property of Z transforms.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. But you're not asking for intuition. You are asking for a formal proof.

Comment: @Trebor is there a simple proof that won't involve advanced math like measure theory? Upon searching, all I see is the change of order of summation with integration

Comment: Are you assuming these are absolutely convergent series? I vaguely remember seeing a proof during undergrad that was a clever manipulation of algebra and the definition of absolute convergence to obtain this result. The proof might even be in an analysis textbook, tbh.

Comment: @moofasa that is most likely the reason why I can't find simple proofs that are based on simple inequalities or algebraic manipulations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Intuition:**
The change of summation work much like you are trying to loop over some $N\times N$ matrix (in your case you take $N\to\infty$). You can go by looking at each rows and within each columns or change it and go by looking at columns and each rows.

In your example lets say $i$ is the row and $j$ is the column index.

*The right hand side:*
$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}$ means that you are looking through all row and $\sum_{j=i}^{\infty}$ means that you are looking for elements below the diagonal(row is already set by $i$ so the column identifies the element $(i, j)$).

*The left hand side:*
$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}$ means that you are looking through all columns and $\sum_{i=1}^{j}$ means again that you are (again) looking for elements below the diagonal(now the column is already set by $j$ so the row identifies the element $(i, j)$).

You could prove that it works for any $N\times N$ matrix by induction.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality chain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{1\leq i\leq j<\infty}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
is already a key to gain some insight for the series transformations. Here we do an index transformation in small steps which might be helpful to better see what's going on.

> Assuming the double series is absolutely convergent, so that we can reorder terms at will, we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=i}^\infty f(i,j)}
> &=\sum_{1\leq i<\infty}\sum_{i\leq j<\infty}f(i,j)\tag{2.1}\\
> &=\sum_{\color{blue}{1\leq i\leq j<\infty}}f(i,j)\tag{2.2}\\
> &=\sum_{1\leq j<\infty}\sum_{1\leq i\leq j}f(i,j)\tag{2.3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^jf(i,j)}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2.1) and (2.3) we just use another common notation without rearranging anything.
- In (2.2) we write the index regions more compactly as one inequality chain, but without changing the index region. This notation implies a rearrangement of the summands.

*Hint:* Note that $i,j$ in $f(i,j)$ are positive integers. So, $f(1,\infty)$ is not an admissible representation. We rather write
\begin{align*}
S_1=f(1,1)+f(1,2)+f(1,3)+\cdots
\end{align*}
to represent $S_1=\sum_{j=1}^\infty f(1,j)$. For the same reasons we also write $1\leq j\color{blue}{<\infty}$.